# How to use urlparam with jQuery to select radiobuttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button, url-parameters

I have this URL: `../foo::bar{2}233{13}171{1}1{20}0.html`

Parameter are in `{}`, values behind.

With this I'm able to get the values:

```
var vars = [], hash;
var q = document.URL.split('bar')[1];
if(q != undefined){
    q = q.split('%7B');
    for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
        hash = q[i].split('%7D');
        vars.push(hash[1]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
};
```

How can I set the matching radio button `selected` to submit a form?

```
<input id="233" type="radio" value="233" name="id[2]">
<label title="orange" for="233">
    <img style="background: #FF6600; color: #668014" src="img/orange.gif">
</label>
```

In addition I'd like to use the `style` of the following `img` as values for styling to other divs. For select on page I have this:

```
$('label img').click(
    function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-color'); 
        var bc = $(this).css('color'); 
        $('.basic').css("background-color", bg);
        $('.detail').css("border-color", bc);
});
```

`document.write(String(vars['2']));` is not enough...